# Reset Button to default background

Tags: java, android

I know that was already asked but it is outdated:

I have 2 buttons that represent 2 choices and if one is selected the background color gets changed to yellow. But if i want to change the choice i need to somehow reset the button:

I already try to set it back but some old design comes out. Can you provide me the id of the modern button style? And show me how to implement it?

```
            int myChoice;

            if (view == findViewById(R.id.choice1)){
                myChoice = 1;
                choice1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.highlightButton));
                choice2.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
            }

            else if (view == findViewById(R.id.choice2)){
                myChoice = 2;
                choice2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.highlightButton));
                choice1.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Tags with getBackground(). This will assure you are always setting back to original.
Add following in beginning of function

```
if (v.getTag() == null)
    v.setTag(v.getBackground());
```

Then instead of `setBackgroundResource`, use

```
v.setBackground(v.getTag());
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323302/reset-android-button-to-default-color-and-style), you can store the default color of the button into a `Drawable` and grab the selection color (Yellow in your case) into anther `Drawable`, then toggle background colors of buttons with these `Drawable` variables

please check below demo

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Drawable mDefaultButtonColor;
    private Drawable mSelectedButtonColor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        final Button btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);

        mDefaultButtonColor = (btn1.getBackground());
        mSelectedButtonColor = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.color.buttonSelected);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggleButton(btn1, true);
                toggleButton(btn2, false);
            }
        });


        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggleButton(btn1, false);
                toggleButton(btn2, true);
            }
        });


    }

    private void toggleButton(Button button, boolean isSelected) {
        button.setBackground(isSelected ? mSelectedButtonColor : mDefaultButtonColor);
    }

}
```