# how to refresh a RecyclerView draw (not datas)?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, refresh, presentation

In a RecyclerView, I change the presentation for some items as follows:

```
        if (stk.getQty() == 0) {    // mise en valeur des stocks à 0 non purgeables
            cellStockQty.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            GradientDrawable border = new GradientDrawable();
            border.setColor(mIV.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAugment));  // white background
            border.setStroke(1, mIV.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));  // black border with full
            mIV.setBackground(border);
        }
```

When I delete an item, I manage to remove it from the display, with notifyItemRemoved(index); but the next item takes the presentation of the item that was deleted.

Of course, if I leave this activity then come back, all is right.

How to make sure to refresh the display, depending on the data?

[before deleting Jjjjjj item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChSfY.jpg)

[after deleting Jjjjjj item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqsdi.jpg)

**Edit:**

Here is my original layout

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:foreground="@drawable/card_foreground"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/stockRecyclerviewBackground"
    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="6dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <include layout="@layout/recystock_cell_include" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that just doing:

```
mStockRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

is enough.

Sorry for the noise.

**Another solution**, found with the help of the answers here and there [Reset Button to default background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54065239/reset-button-to-default-background) is to reset the background, using setTag() and getTag() like:

```
if ( mIV.getTag() == null ) mIV.setTag(mIV.getBackground());
if (cellStockQty.getTag() == null ) cellStockQty.setTag(cellStockQty.getCurrentTextColor());
if (stk.getQty() == 0) {    // mise en valeur des stocks à 0 non purgeables
    cellStockQty.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    GradientDrawable border = new GradientDrawable();
    border.setColor(mIV.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAugment));  // white background
    border.setStroke(1, mIV.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));  // black border with full
    mIV.setBackground(border);
} else {
    cellStockQty.setTextColor((int)cellStockQty.getTag());
    mIV.setBackground((Drawable) mIV.getTag());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to clear background `mIV.setBackground(null);`
in else statement.

Comment: I can't use null because I have another original background in the layout. How can I reset it?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your onBindViewHolder is broken.  A properly written onBindViewHolder sets EVERY field of the view that could possibly change.  And in a proper RecyclerView implementation, non of the click handlers or other actions ever touch the view itself, they all change the model then notify the adapter an iten has changed.  Obviously you're not doing that-  you're inheriting some of the styling from the old view.  Fix your onBindViewHolder to specify all of the view information.

Comment: The problem is that all the others presentation informations come from the layout itself.

Comment: @Chris972 Then you're doing RecyclerViews wrong and need to fix it so that doesn't happen.  Or if the layouts for different elements are really different, they need to be different view types with separate view holder types.

Comment: not so different, just textColor and border background to highlight certain elements, no more, as shown in my code.
All items are presentated in the same way, except some I have to highlight but maybe the problem is here, and I don't use the good way to highlight them.

Comment: Like I said-  any visual property difference between two items with the same view type MUST be set in onBindViewHolder for ALL items its called on.  Otherwise you get bugs like this.  So you need to fix your onBindViewHolder to set all of those fields every time its called.